deploying blitzjs app to vercel error - working on local
using blitz build && blitz start on my local machine works, no errors and it just works, however on vercel, after pushing changes to github, vercel does it thing building / compiling the app, and it is the only thing that works and just give a white screen with text: "Something went wrong! Try Again", not rendering anything.
here is the log error on vercel:
Error: Usage of `useAuthenticatedBlitzContext` is supported only in next.js 13.0.0 and above. Please upgrade your next.js version.
    at /var/task/.next/server/chunks/285.js:112:12642
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /var/task/.next/server/chunks/285.js:112:10296
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __async$1 (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/285.js:112:10116)
    at getBlitzContext (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/285.js:112:11997)
    at /var/task/.next/server/chunks/285.js:112:74680
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /var/task/.next/server/chunks/285.js:112:74581
    at new Promise (<anonymous>) {
  digest: '2099296089'
}

and here's my package.json file
"dependencies": {
    "@blitzjs/auth": "2.0.5",
    "@blitzjs/next": "2.0.5",
    "@blitzjs/rpc": "2.0.5",
    "@prisma/client": "5.4.2",
    "blitz": "2.0.8",
    "formik": "2.4.5",
    "next": "14.2.2",
    "prisma": "5.4.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "secure-password": "4.0.0",
    "zod": "3.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@next/env": "13.4.19",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "8.0.1",
    "@types/node": "18.11.9",
    "@types/preview-email": "2.0.1",
    "@types/react": "18.0.25",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.42.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "2.2.0",
    "ajv": "^7.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.18",
    "eslint": "8.27.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.5.0",
    "husky": "8.0.2",
    "jsdom": "20.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "13.0.3",
    "postcss": "8.4.35",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "prettier-plugin-prisma": "4.4.0",
    "pretty-quick": "3.1.3",
    "preview-email": "3.0.7",
    "tailwindcss": "3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "3.6.0",
    "vitest": "0.25.3"
  }


It seems this a problem with Vercel itself: https://github.com/blitz-js/blitz/issues/4309#issuecomment-1986900611
As an aside, I noticed that your @blitz/* library dependencies are pinned to older versions (2.0.5) than your main blitz version (2.0.8).
"@blitzjs/auth": "2.0.5",
"@blitzjs/next": "2.0.5",
"@blitzjs/rpc": "2.0.5",
"@prisma/client": "5.4.2",
"blitz": "2.0.8"

